# Getting error including handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I just started playing with handlebars.js and am getting an error from within handlebars.js which seems very odd : "define is not defined" . If someone can point out my mistake, I'd much appreciate it. Below is my code snippet and below that is a pix of the chrome dev tools error.

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
            {{body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.amd.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    })
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any reason you are referencing the amd file? if not here is the cdn not throwing the error.

```html
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
            {{body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    })
</script>
```